# Highcharts organisation chart with a lot of nodes isnt looking good

Tags: model-view-controller, highcharts

Im using Highcharts's organisation chart to create an image of a datastructure that has a tree layout. The Highcharts technology seems to work just fine, however when i want to use a lot of nodes, the nodes get packed together and the lines end up overlapping. This way i'm no longer able to see the links between the nodes.

I have been trying to use CSS parameters to change the layout wich wasnt working out well. I also tried setting the layout to hanging however this totally ruins the layout.

This is what i mean by overlapping lines: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QEQv.jpg

```
Here is a sample of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/byv7kea1/
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?

Comment: Good question, i have updated my post with a link.The problem is visible on the E level, depending on the with of your monitor. This is what the problem looks like: https://imgur.com/a/mjJ6CzR

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the default layout ([Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.nodes.layout)) from `normal` to `hanging` like that :

```
...
nodes:[
    {
    id:"D1",
    name: "D1",
    layout: "hanging",
  },
    {
    id:"D2",
    name: "D2",
    layout: "hanging",
  },
    {
    id:"D3",
    name: "D3",
    layout: "hanging",
  },
]
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/1Lpafdbm/)